# Remove a file from Git history without deleting the file

Tags: git

I used GitHub's [instructions for scrubbing a file from the commit history](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/), but it deleted the file in question from my system. This was surprising to me because the `git rm --cached` command itself should leave the file itself untouched. But this behavior can also be seen in the worked example on that page: try running `ls` before and after the big `git filter-branch ...` command.

I'm using Git 2.6.1.

How can I delete a file from the commit history *without* deleting the file itself? Obviously I could just make a backup (which I did in my case), but that's a workaround and not a solution.

Comment: Making a backup is the solution.

Comment: Git is primarily a Unix program.  In Unix, you don't integrate every freaking scenario into your executable. You make (hopefully) small separate programs cooperate to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `git-filter-branch` is done it checks out the new branch head. This will update your working directory to a clean state. The file you wanted obliterated from history has been obliterated. Backing up beforehand is the solution.

If you forgot to back it up, you can still get it back!  Git takes a long time to throw things out, your original commits are still in there.  After `git-filter-branch` there will be a branch called `original/refs/heads/master` (if you filtered master) which contains the original commits.  You can recover the file from there.

In general, you can recover filters and rebases using `git reflog`. It's a log of every time `HEAD` changes (ie. you checkout or rebase or merge or filter or...). For example, after doing the Github filter example, `git reflog` is...

```
abaabaf (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{0}: filter-branch: rewrite
8ef0c30 (refs/original/refs/remotes/origin/master, refs/original/refs/heads/master) HEAD@{1}: clone:
```

I can use `8ef0c30` or `HEAD@{1}` (ie. the previous location of `HEAD`) or `original/refs/remotes/origin/master` or `original/refs/heads/master` to get back to where things were before the filter ran.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. This point needs to be clarified in the guide I linked in the question.

Answer (score 4):

## First of all:

(It needs to be said.)

When using `git filter-branch` you are doing *history rewriting* in an *automated* manner according to your own (maybe buggy) specification. Thus **you should make a backup of your repo** before doing that, **anyway**, or perform the operation on a fresh separate clone of your repo.

## Why the file also vanishes from your working copy

`git filter-branch` applies the specified command to each applicable commit. However, it doesn't check out those commits in your working copy to do that. Instead, it checks them out into `.git-rewrite/` by default, or to the directory you gave with the `-d` option. (See [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) documentation, option **-d <directory>**.)

After having rewritten the applicable commits, Git checks out the resulting new branch. As this is a switch from a branch with the file (the pre-rewrite version of that branch) to one without the file (the post-rewrite version of that branch), the file is deleted from your working copy, too.

## How you can preserve the file

Well, make a backup.

(Note that a tag or branch won't be an adequate backup if you're rewriting all branches and all tags as is done in the example at https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/.)

## How you can retrieve the file if you haven't done that

See [Schwern's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33333422/674064).